# Force aware time in python

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any way to force all time objects in Python
to be aware, perhaps generating an error if I try to
generate a naïve object?

Is there a way to tell whether a time object is naïve?

Trusting code to be non-naïve is not working for me
and I'm getting bitten.

Comment: What is a "time object" exactly and are they always created the same way?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I should have been more precise.
It's a datetime object.

Comment: If they're all created the same way, then you should be able to monkey-patch the `datetime` module and add a check for naive-ness.

Answer (score 0):

To tell if a datetime object is aware check its tzinfo attribute, as per the [datetime doc says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

> ```
> A datetime object d is aware if both of the following hold:
>
> d.tzinfo is not None
>
> d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d) does not return None
>
> Otherwise, d is naive.
>
> A time object t is aware if both of the following hold:
>
> t.tzinfo is not None
>
> t.tzinfo.utcoffset(None) does not return None.
> ```

As to how to force all datetimes to not be naive, there is a problem. Sometimes one simply does not have the timezone info.

Comment: Yes that's true some times, but the script I'm writing now always has and uses aware datetime objects.  But being new to python (coming from perl), I am sometimes getting objects that look like local time but are naive, and then daylight time goes awry.  So, if there is a flag in the class that I can set that would error out if trying to create naive, that would be very useful.

Comment: I know of no such flag, but I suppose you could create a child class that has that feature.

Comment: It just occurred to me:  if one doesn't know the timezone, one doesn't know what moment is being represented.  Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Why not override `datetime.datetime.__new__` in a subclass?

Notice how the method `datetime.datetime.__new__` checks the timezone argument before creating [new instances](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6104013838e181e3c698cb07316f449a0c31ea96/Lib/datetime.py#L1563) by calling the module level function:

```
# cpython/Lib/datetime.py
def _check_tzinfo_arg(tz):
    if tz is not None and not isinstance(tz, tzinfo):
        raise TypeError("tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass")
```

So we can invoke a similar check before calling `datetime.datetime.__new__` in our subclass

```
import datetime

class AwareDate(datetime.datetime):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(kwargs.get('tzinfo', None), datetime.tzinfo):
            raise ValueError('MUST BE TZ AWARE !')

        return datetime.datetime.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Some quick tests

```
normaldate = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
awaredate = AwareDate(2020, 12, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
assert awaredate == normaldate

normaldate = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20)
awaredate = AwareDate(2020, 12, 20) # ValueError: MUST BE TZ AWARE!
```

Comment: Or if you're feeling adventurous - you can always change `_check_tzinfo_arg(tz)` directly in `lib/datetime.py` (:

Comment: Thanks for posting that; my python wasn't strong enough to do it on my own.  There are a few places on the web that say "just don't use naive", I concur, and hope something like this becomes available in the standard library someday.

Comment: Well a quick and dirty way to implement the AwareDate above is to put it in another module XXX.py - and later on instead of doing `from datetime import datetime` just do `from XXX import AwareDate as datetime`. That way, you can get the "tz checking" you want without absolutely no changes in your actual code.